# What is the difference between Firebase SetValue() and SetValueAsync() methods and when to use them?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Official documentation does not show any meaningful difference between SetValue() and SetValueAsync():

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference

```
1. void setValue(Object value, DatabaseReference.CompletionListener listener)

    Description: Set the data at this location to the given value.


2. ApiFuture<Void> setValueAsync(Object value)

    Description: Set the data at this location to the given value.
```

What are the implications of using the "async" method ?

What is the meaning of "ApiFuture" ?

I'm planning to use these methods to save a string. This string is as large as a page of a book. What is the recommended method to implement it ?

Answer (score 1):

The non-async method will block until the operation completes.

The async methods are asynchronous and return immediately.  The work completes some time later, which can be tracked by the returned ApiFuture.

[Learn about asynchronous operations with the Firebase Admin Java SDK](https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-asynchronous-operations-with-admin-java-sdk-82ca9b4f6022).

[Learn about ApiFuture](https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/1.1.0/apidocs/com/google/api/core/ApiFuture.html).  You add a listener to it in order to find out when the operation completes.

Both the async and non-async method both work fine.  Pick the one that best suits your situation.

Comment: Are you sure this is the real behaviour in Java? Just asking because the `setValue` method has a completion-listener parameter, which is called from some firebase thread seconds later. Also when debugging a call to `setValue()` returns instantly

Comment: Agree with Tom my tests in Google Cloud App Engine indicate that they are both non-blocking. Check more details on my answer to another question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837734/3841493